# How to grab a word from ALPHANEUMERIC field in apex

Tags: apex, string

I have a field with names like 12GOLD, 13GOLD.2 ,16SILVER.4, 18PLATINUM.3 etc.

I need to just get the alpha part of those words like GOLD/SILVER/PLATINUM.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use Regular Expressions for such functionality. Here is a demonstration anonymous script:

```
String input = '12GOLD, 13GOLD.2 ,16SILVER.4, 18PLATINUM.3';

Set<String> words = new Set<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile('[a-zA-Z]+').matcher(input);
while (m.find()) words.add(m.group());

system.debug(words);
```

Resulting log:

> USER_DEBUG [8]|DEBUG|{GOLD, PLATINUM, SILVER}

Comment: Or just use [`'12GOLD, 1,3GOLD.2 ,16SILVER.4, 18PLATINUM.3'.replaceAll('[^a-zA-Z]', '');`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_replaceAll)

Comment: Except then you would have gold twice.

Comment: It's unclear, but I believe `12GOLD, 13GOLD.2 ,16SILVER.4, 18PLATINUM.3` are examples of 4 different values for the field

Comment: The OP lists desired output of gold/silver/platinum. I do not see it as unclear.